# Exclude directory in URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have this code at my web.config

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

and I want that specific directories will exclude of this rule.
How can I do it?

Comment: I'm hardly familiar with the problem domain at all, but I just wanted to offer the thought that perhaps the url attribute of the match node allows you to specify full regular expressions. If so, you could list your directories in there. The other option to consider would be virtual directories but again, these are total guesses.

Comment: What directories? Please provide few examples

Comment: lets say that I want to exclude contact and presentaion

also, if I want to block a directory from viewing (my db directory - access - it's a very small website) and the directory is at "db/site" directory

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 15):

To exclude specific folders (`/contact/`, `/presentation/`, `/db/site/` -- anything in these folders) from being processed by this rule, you can add one more condition, like this:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(contact|presentation|db/site)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

It is good to do via additional condition because it is easy to read/understand what this rule is about.

---

If you are good with regex in general, then you may prefer this approach: move such condition into match pattern (you will have the same result in the end and it will be tiny bit faster .. but a bit more difficult to read):

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(?!(?:contact|presentation|db/site)/)(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: @Chaofix If this solved your issue then please consider marking this answer as accepted, thnx.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If I try to go to "/contact/admin" I get the "default.asp" form the root directory - every page under "contact" directory return the "default.asp" of the root... Please advice - I tried both examples - The regex eample return 404 error... :-(

Comment: Won't matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" exclude ALL directories from this rule?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got my blog directory to work with code ignitor in root and wordpress in /blog/

The blog folder also has the original web.config file which is just the second rule of this file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
        <rules>        
            <rule name="wordpress - Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blog" ignoreCase="false"/>
                <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/blog/index.php"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="app" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```